# no funciona DISTINCT mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

la primer columna es **ppidpedido**.

por que me sigue repitiendo el pp.id_pedido si estoy usando DISTINCT

aqui esta mi query y una imagen.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(pp.id_pedido) AS ppidpedido, pp.medical,P.id_pedido,P.urgente,P.confirmado,P.envio_dom,P.enviosucursal,Px.id_paciente,Px.nombre_completo,TP.tipo_pedido,E.etapa_es,FS.pagado,(SELECT OB.observacion FROM observaciones OB INNER JOIN historial HI ON OB.id_observacion = HI.id_observacion WHERE HI.id_pedido = P.id_pedido ORDER BY OB.id_observacion DESC LIMIT 1) observacion,P.creado,P.modificado,TC.mexicano tcalzado,Suc.nombre sucursal,DE.direccion_env,es.sincronizado,es.archivo FROM pedidos P 
LEFT JOIN pacientes Px ON P.id_paciente = Px.id_paciente 
LEFT JOIN tipo_pedido TP ON P.id_tipopedido = TP.id_tipopedido 
LEFT JOIN etapas E ON P.id_etapa = E.id_etapa 
LEFT JOIN finanzas_suc FS ON P.id_finanzassuc = FS.id_finanzassuc 
LEFT JOIN cat_tallacalzado TC ON Px.id_tallacalzado = TC.id_tallacalzado 
LEFT JOIN sucursales Suc ON P.id_sucursal = Suc.id_sucursal 
LEFT JOIN direcciones_envios DE ON P.id_enviodom = DE.id_direccionenv 
LEFT JOIN estudios es ON P.id_estudio = es.id_estudio inner join productos_pedidos pp on P.id_pedido=pp.id_pedido 
WHERE P.id_sucursal = 51 ORDER BY P.modificado DESC LIMIT 0, 255
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que haci me quedo bien

```
    SELECT DISTINCT pp.id_pedido,(select pps.medical from productos_pedidos pps where pps.id_pedido=P.id_pedido and pps.medical=1 limit 1) medical,P.id_pedido,P.urgente,P.confirmado,P.envio_dom,P.enviosucursal,Px.id_paciente,Px.nombre_completo,TP.tipo_pedido,E.etapa_es,FS.pagado,(SELECT OB.observacion FROM observaciones OB 
INNER JOIN historial HI ON OB.id_observacion = HI.id_observacion WHERE HI.id_pedido = P.id_pedido ORDER BY OB.id_observacion DESC LIMIT 1) observacion,P.creado,P.modificado,TC.mexicano tcalzado,Suc.nombre sucursal,DE.direccion_env,es.sincronizado,es.archivo FROM pedidos P 
LEFT JOIN pacientes Px ON P.id_paciente = Px.id_paciente 
LEFT JOIN tipo_pedido TP ON P.id_tipopedido = TP.id_tipopedido 
LEFT JOIN etapas E ON P.id_etapa = E.id_etapa 
LEFT JOIN finanzas_suc FS ON P.id_finanzassuc = FS.id_finanzassuc 
LEFT JOIN cat_tallacalzado TC ON Px.id_tallacalzado = TC.id_tallacalzado 
LEFT JOIN sucursales Suc ON P.id_sucursal = Suc.id_sucursal 
LEFT JOIN direcciones_envios DE ON P.id_enviodom = DE.id_direccionenv 
LEFT JOIN estudios es ON P.id_estudio = es.id_estudio 
inner join productos_pedidos pp on P.id_pedido=pp.id_pedido 
WHERE P.id_sucursal = 51 ORDER BY P.modificado DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: La imagen no coincide con el código. Tienes un alias `ppidpedido` y no veo esa columna en la captura. ¿?

Comment: la primer columna es ppidpedido

Comment: Observa bien que el `DISTINCT` que buscas está en esta tabla `productos_pedidos` pero haces una serie de `JOIN` en la consulta que pueden resultar en varias filas para esa columna. Quizá la consulta está mal planteada ¿? me parece extraño que un campo requerido `DISTINCT` hayas puesto su tabla tan lejos en la consulta. ¿Por qué esa tabla no está primero? Puedes empezar por ahí, escribe una consulta simple: `SELECT DISTINCT(pp.id_pedido) ppidpedido FROM productos_pedidos` y observa los resultados. Luego ve agregando los `JOIN` uno por uno para ver dónde está la inconsistencia de datos.

Comment: se tiene que hacer una left join entre pedidos y productos pedidos  . 1- pedido puede tener como ejemplo 3 pedidos y lo que se pidio en primera fue mostrar los pedidos por eso la tabla productos pedidos esta mas lejos .

Comment: al parecer ya me quedo

Comment: DISTINCT no es una función, por lo tanto no afecta a una columna. DISTINCT es una opción del SELECT para eliminar filas repetidas.